# XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode not always working accurately

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

I am having an interesting issue with C# and selecting xml nodes consistently.

Our site is in the process of being upgraded from classic ASP to ASP.NET. In order to make the process smoother for visitors while we upgrade, I implemented a 404 redirect to take visitors to the new .aspx that replaced old .asp pages for the case of external links, bookmarks, etc.

Some of the links just changed from .asp to .aspx, but some changed structure and naming, so I have an XML file which follows this pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<links>
    <link oldUrl="/jailpod/default.asp" newUrl="/about/construction/jailpod.aspx" />
    <link oldURL="/boc/boards.asp" newUrl="/boc/boards/default.aspx" />
    <link oldUrl="/maps.asp" newUrl="/maps/default.aspx" />
</links>
```

This XML file is used by our custom 404 page in the C# code behind. The code goes through the process of looking for a replacement URL by searching for a new one in the XML file, seeing if the page simply changed to .aspx, and finally if no match was found staying on the 404 page to let the visitor know they have an incorrect page.

Here is the C# code:

```
    // Whether or not to display an additional message to the users
    bool redirectVisitor = false;

    string url = ExtractUrlFrom(Request.Url.ToString());

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/inc/NewUrlDictionary.xml"));

    XmlNode urlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(
        string.Format("/links/link[@oldUrl='{0}']", url));

            // Check if the node existed or not
            if (urlNode != null)
            {
                url = urlNode.Attributes["newUrl"].Value;
                redirectVisitor = true;
            }
            else
            {
               ....
            }
        }
```

Here is the issue.

**When I visit:**

mysite/jailpod/default.asp

OR

mysite/maps.asp

I am redirected as I would expect.

**When I visit:**

mysite/boc/boards.asp

No XmlNode is found, and thus the 404 page just tells me it does not exist. I have stepped through the C# code using a break point and the URL it is searching for is exactly "/boc/boards.asp" and I even used the Visual Studio locals panel to look through the contents of the XmlDocument object, and it does indeed have a node with the attribute"/boc/boards.asp"

This is not an isolated issue with that one node, there are (seemingly random) other nodes where it occurs as well.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? I am considering just migrating all of these XML records into our database and just querying the database instead -- unless I am just making a silly mistake somewhere here.

Comment: I've removed most of unrelated code... Note that in addition to wrong attribute names (as answers say) you have issue with case sensitive comparison of Urls - unless you care about case of the urls I'd recommend to normalize them to consistent case before searching in XML, or even better use LINQ to XML and search with case non-sensitive comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I actually have all lower case in my XML document, but that does not prevent visitors from providing upper case -- I will use .ToLower() on the url I provide as a search term to avoid case sensitive mismatches. I'll take a look at LINQ to XML; I haven't used it yet but I really like LINQ so I'll give it a go.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Also, I implemented the "ExtractUrlFrom()" method you showed in my trimmed code example. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xml attributes are case sensitive. You've got oldURL instead of oldUrl in your second xml element.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was such a simple issue and I overlooked it for so long. Thank you so much for the quick response!

I had a few sporadically placed "oldURL" nodes in my XML document and I had completely forgotten to look at case sensitivity when troubleshooting. I can't believe I wasted so much time on such a silly mistake on my part!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your source XML document, the attribute for oldUrl for the one you are having a problem with has a different case than the other entries.  xpath is case sensitive.